# Deleting row in table in sqlite DB from R

Tags: r, shiny, dt, rsqlite

I am building a shiny application which will allow CRUD operations by a user on a table which exists in an sqlite3 database. I am using the `input$table_rows_selected()` function in `DT` to get the index of the rows selected by the user. I am then trying to delete the rows (using an action button `deleteRows`) from the database which have a matching timestamp (the epoch time stored as the primary key). The following code runs without any error but does not delete the selected rows.

```
observeEvent(input$deleteRows, {

  if(!is.null(input$responsesTable_rows_selected)){
    s=input$responsesTable_rows_selected

    conn <- poolCheckout(pool)

    lapply(length(s), function(i){
      timestamp = rvsTL$data[s[i],8]

      query <- glue::glue_sql("DELETE FROM TonnageListChartering
                          WHERE TonnageListChartering.timestamp = {timestamp}
                          ", .con = conn)

      dbExecute(conn, sqlInterpolate(ANSI(), query))
    })

    poolReturn(conn)
    # Show a modal when the button is pressed
    shinyalert("Success!", "The selected rows have been deleted. Refresh
             the table by pressing F5", type = "success")
  }

})
```

`pool` is a handler at the global level for connecting to the database.

```
pool <- pool::dbPool(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(),
                     dbname="data/compfleet.db")
```

Why does this not work? And if it did, is there any way of refreshing the datatable output without having to reload the application?

Comment: Have you tried printing the query to see if it really matches what you're trying to delete? My guess is that something funky is going with timestamp.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I checked it. Seems to be fine. This is what the query generates when I click on a particular row `DELETE FROM TonnageListChartering
WHERE TonnageListChartering.timestamp = 1534569538`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @RomanLustrik there was definitely something 'funky' going on with `timestamp`. I am not well versed with `sqlite` but running `PRAGMA table_info(TonnageListChartering);` revealed this:

```
0|vesselName||0||0
1|empStatus||0||0
2|openPort||0||0
3|openDate||0||0
4|source||0||0
5|comments||0||0
6|updatedBy||0||0
7|timestamp||0||1
8|VesselDetails||0||0
9|Name||0||0
10|VslType||0||0
11|Cubic||0||0
12|DWT||0||0
13|IceClass||0||0
14|IMO||0||0
15|Built||0||0
16|Owner||0||0
```

I guess none of the variables have a data type defined and I am not sure if that's possible to do it now. Anyway, I changed the `query` to ensure that the timestamp is in quotes.

```
query <- glue::glue_sql("DELETE FROM TonnageListChartering
                          WHERE TonnageListChartering.timestamp = '{timestamp}'
                          ", .con = conn)
```

This deletes the user selected rows.

However, when I am left with only one row, I am unable to delete it. No idea why. Maybe because of a primary key that I have defined while creating the table?